# regex to only allow an input to 3 decimal places with 0.001 being the smallest number possible, not 0

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a regex to allow a user enter a positive number and to 3 decimal places. My regex looks like this, however, it isn't working as I would like.

```
/\d*[1-9](\.\d{0,3})?/
```

This allows the user to enter `1.000` as the smallest number, however, it doesn't allow a user to enter `0.001` which should be the smallest number possible to enter into the input.

Does anyone know what the regex should be to solve this?

Comment: How are you implementing this regex? Why not just check if the input is >= 0.001?

Comment: Another non-regex solution would be match it against `number.toFixed(3)`, which satisfies the "3 decimal places" requirement.

Comment: That code would not allow `10.001`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just check for 0 and make the regex a lot simpler, but here is a solution, where the required decimal places can be adjusted by changing {1,3}.

The jist of this regex is that we allow any number greater than two digits , then allow only 1-9 for one digit, then optionally require up to 1 decimal with 1-3 digits afterwards.

```js
const r = /^((([0-9]{2,}){1}|[1-9]{1})(\.[0-9]{1,3}){0,1})$/;
const tests = ['1','2','0','1.001','1.001.1','999.001','9.01','9.0100','abc'];
tests.forEach(t=>console.log(t,r.test(t)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has another issue where it can not match 10 since you are not allowing the ones place to be 0.

You need to use some or statements

```js
const re = /(^([1-9]|\d{2,})(\.\d{0,3})?|0\.\d{0,2}[1-9])$/
const tests = ["0.001", "0.1", "0","0.0", "0.000","10.001", "10","11","1"]
tests.forEach(n => console.log(n, re.test(n)))
```

Comment: hey, this isn't really working for me. One issue is I can only type up to decimal places i.e `1.22`. If I try `1.222` it doesn't allow this

Answer (score 1):

```js
const re = /^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/
const tests = ["0.001", "0.1", "0","0.0", "0.000","10.001", "10","11","1","1.22","1.222"]
tests.forEach(n => console.log(n, re.test(n)))
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of string
  (?!           # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    0+          # 1 or more zero
    (?:         # start non capture group
      \.        # a dot
      0+        # 1 or more zero
    )?          # end group, optional
    $           # end of string
  )             # end lookahead
  \d+           # 1 or more digits
  (?:           # start non capture group
    \.          # a dot
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
  )?            # end group, optionnal
$               # end of string
```

Comment: I really like the regex explanation, is there like a tool that spits that out?

Comment: I agree. looks neat.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound: No tools here, I've written this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a negative lookahead to assert from the start of the string what is on the right is neither a dot or zero repeated until the end of the string:

```
^(?![0.]+$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MeY6Dg/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?![0.]+$)` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not what is listed in the character class repeated 1+ times until the end of the string
- `\d+` Match 1+ times a digit
- `(?:\.\d{1,3})?` Optional non capturing group which matches a dot and 1+ times a digit
- `$` End of the string

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tests = ["0.001", "0.1", "0","0.0", "0.000","10.001", "10","11","1","1.22","1.222"]
tests.forEach(n => console.log(parseFloat(n) >= 0.001))
```

I really think this is being overthought.

Comment: parseFloat returns the number for any string that starts with a number as well, so it is not a good solution. e.g. `parseFloat('10.0a1')` returns `10`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is here.

```
([1-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0]\.[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[0]\.[0][1-9][0-9]|[0]\.[0][0][1-9])
```

This should match 0.001~9.999

Comment: The title says "with 0.001 being the smallest number possible, not 0"

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't say "less than 10"

Comment: Does 1.000 is the largest number? I will modify the answer later.

Comment: There's no upper bound in OP's requirements.

Comment: After your edit it doesn't match, for example, 0.020

Comment: Ok, but it still has an upper bound, which the answer doesn't specify (so one should assume there is none). See [here](https://regex101.com/r/fOD0yo/1)

Comment: If the precision class is 1/1000. it could be 999.9, 99.99, 9.999, 0.999 to 0.001. The condition will be more complicated.